# How to count all rows by criteria and no more than 10

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to count all rows which satisfies the specifiec requrements and no more than 10. What do I mean is that:

if `rowsCountWithRestriction > 10` then print `10`

otherwise print the actual rows count. But I can't quite take and write if-else such that:

```
Integer count;
Criteria criteria;

//restricting the criteria

if(rowsCount > 10){
    count = 10;
} else {
    count = (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

because I actually have much more complicated `Restrictor` abstraction which is applying restrictions to the criteria. It looks as

```
public interface CriteriaRestrictor {

    public void applyTo(Criteria criteria);

}
```

I tried the following criteria query:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Entity.class);
//setting restrictions
criteria.setMaxResult(10);
Integer count = (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

But it didn't work and printed all number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
criteria.setMaxResults(10);
Integer count = criteria.list().size();
if (count > 10) { 
    return 10; 
}
else { 
    return count;
}
```

... one way to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sure you yourself knows that it's not a good way because of retrivieng all entities.

Comment: You can do that after your .setMaxResults(10) call as well, @user3663882